# Plugin with id 'jacoco' not found + Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, gradle, jacoco

I'm trying to add jacoco support to my gradle project, but when I add the jacoco plugin, it gives me an error.

Here is my gradle.build

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { gradleVersion = '1.11' }
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'project-report'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

eclipse {
  classpath { downloadSources=true }
}

eclipse.classpath.file {
  // Classpath entry for Eclipse which changes the order of classpathentries; otherwise no sources for 3rd party jars are shown
  withXml { xml ->
    def node = xml.asNode()
    node.remove( node.find { it.@path == 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container' } )
    node.appendNode( 'classpathentry', [ kind: 'con', path: 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container', exported: 'true'])
  }
}

tasks.withType(Compile) { options.encoding = 'UTF-8' }

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
  providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
  runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2'

  compile 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:2.2.5.RELEASE'
  compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.2.RELEASE'
  compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.0.2.RELEASE'
  compile 'org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.2.RELEASE'
  compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.4.0.RELEASE'
  compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.2.1.RELEASE'
  compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.2.1.RELEASE'

  compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.1'
  compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.2.0'
  compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.11.4'

  compile 'c3p0:c3p0:0.9.1.2'
  compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.4.Final'
  compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:4.3.4.Final'
  compile 'org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.0.0'

  compile 'com.google.guava:guava:16.0'
  compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'

  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
  compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13'
  compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'

  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
  testCompile 'commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2'
  testCompile 'org.springframework:spring-test:4.0.2.RELEASE'
  testCompile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.2.0'
  testCompile 'de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:1.35'
  testCompile 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test:2.2.5.RELEASE'

  compile localGroovy()
}

test {
  testLogging { // Show that tests are run in the command-line output
    events 'started', 'passed' }
  exclude 'com/bambilon/All*'
  exclude 'com/bambilon/**/slow/*'
}
```

and when I run refresh dependencies in Eclipse, it gives me this error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin with id 'jacoco' not found.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.getTypeForId(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.getTypeForId(DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.apply(DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyPlugin(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.apply(AbstractProject.java:846)
    at org.gradle.api.Project$apply.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
    at org.gradle.api.Script$apply.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
```

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Which version of gradle is eclipse using?

Comment: Hi Tim for bringing that up! I had 2 versions installed 1.10 and 1.11. I removed 1.10 and I forced Eclipse to use 1.11, instead of taking it from the build.gradle file. It is not showing the error anymore, although I'm not sure the plugin is working. 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure which version introdueced `jacoco` plugin but with Gradle 2.x it for sure works. If you have a `$buildDir/jacoco` folder after running `gradle build`, you can be sure that it works. More information on http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html.

Answer (score 0):

I have also got the same problem , I have set the gradle path  in eclipse .It  sloved for me.To set the path

> Eclipse -Window->preference-type Gardle

Click on folder radio button , and set path  to gradle folder located in your system.